# How can you express (1234) in S4 as a product of disjoint cycles?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations

In S4, how would you express (1234) as disjoint cycles?

I did try almost every possible case (12)(34) or (13)(24)   (14)(23)

none of these mathces with 1234

Comment: It already *is* a cycle.

Answer (score 2):

As noted in the comments, $(1234)$ is already a cycle and hence is a product of disjoint cycles. Product is perhaps used a bit loosely here, but by most definitions an element standing alone is a product with $1$ factor, and a product with $0$ factors is usually defined to be the identity element. This is just something to get used to, and most would agree that these definitions are useful because in many cases we avoid having to treat $1$ and $0$ differently.

For example, the fundamental theorem of arithmetic says that every positive integer is a product of primes. This includes prime numbers, which are products of $1$ prime, as well as $1$, which is a product of $0$ primes.

Comment: so (1234) is itself a product of disjoint cycles?

Comment: Yes. It is a product of $1$ cycle, $(1234)$, which is disjoint from all other cycles in the product (because there are no other cycles in the product).

Comment: Even if you had a non-trivial situation (more than one cycle), you never have to try and guess to find the expression as a product of disjoint cycles. Just compute the product in hand. If you do it correctly, the result is expressed as a product of disjoint cycles.